Filtering an Array (not Range) based on a SUM of CHOOSECOLS applied to it
I have a series of cells with variations of a long formula which involves filters.
It takes a certain array, does some counting to some of its columns (checking the number of nonempty cells, then the number of positive cells), but then I need to filter that array further based on the sum of certain of its columns. The important nuance is that I need this formula to be pretty uniform, only changing the first two variables (label and countedColumns) for ease of mass implementation. This seemed to work great until I had to reference the proper cells inside the row for the sake of filtering, and to sum the values of those cells.
So far I tried something roughly like this (failing at the filtering stage):
=LET(
label, " SomeLabel ",
countedColumns, {30,33},

array, IF(ArrayOfTheDay!$A$3:$ZZ$999="","",ArrayOfTheDay!$A$3:$ZZ$999),

countedCells, CHOOSECOLS(array, countedColumns),
countedCellsClean, IF(countedCells="","",countedCells),
attemptCount, SUMPRODUCT(--(countedCellsClean<>"")),
successCount, SUM(countedCellsClean),

filteredSuccessData, FILTER(array, SUM(CHOOSECOLS(array,countedColumns)>0)), // this is not working
listOfSuccessDataAsText, // this will TextJoin/Concatenate certain cells from List

successCountText, IF(successCount>0, successCount&": ", "-"),
attemptCountText, IF(attemptsCount>0, " attempts: "&attemptCount, ""),
CONCATENATE(label, successCountText, ": ", listOfSuccessDataAsText," separator ", attemptCountText)
)

How can I properly choose the right columns within a row for the sake of filtering rows based on their sums, or how else can I approach it so as to not need to specify the columns multiple times per such formula? (I.e. I would rather not have to manually write a bunch of (column1address>0)+(column2address>0)+() entries in each and every instance of this filter, and it would be best not to use addresses at all.)

Don't you mean N(CHOOSECOLS(array,countedColumns)>0) instead of SUM(CHOOSECOLS(array,countedColumns)>0) ? You can't sum TRUE or FALSE it needs converted to 1 or 0 first. If you SUM it it also returns a single 1 or 0, not an array.

Also hitCount is not declared

Sorry, hitCount is how it was called in a previous iteration before I turned it into the one for the example. Will fix.

The second argument of FILTER expects an array with the same number of rows as the first argument.  However, SUM returns a single scalar value, not an array.
If you want to turn multiple columns into a single column containing their sum, then use the MMULT function
summedColumn, MMULT(countedCells,--TRANSPOSE(INDEX(countedCells,1,)=INDEX(countedCells,1,))), 

filteredSuccessData, FILTER(array, summedColumn>0)

or the ByRow function:
summedColumn, ByRow(countedCells, LAMBDA(rw, SUM(rw))), 

filteredSuccessData, FILTER(array, summedColumn>0)


Using a ByRow approach worked. It seems I expected Excel to have more implicit support for 'arrayification' of certain functions and for implicit conversions between booleans and number values (for some reason I remembered that some sort of implicit interchangeability exists).

@vicky_molokh the issue there is… when you do a SUM, do you want to SUM by columns, and return a single row?  SUM by rows, and return a single column?  Or SUM everything and return a single value?  It's a bit too ambiguous for Excel to work out what your requirements are in the context

FILTER(array,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(array,countedColumns)>0))

The FILTER function requires the second argument to be an array of the same height as the first argument but SUM produces a sing value only.
Guessing you want to compare the sum of column1 and column2 with a given number in each row, your formula should look like:
FILTER(array,CHOOSECOLS(array,30)+CHOOSECOLS(array,33)>0)


Thanks for the advice, but for me it was important to be able to just plug in countedColumns instead of rewriting the filter formula like this for different applications. (The ByRow method above did fit the goal, OTOH.)
